Normalize polygon coordinate in python
I am trying to normalize the coordinate two polygon. However, after normalizing they just overlap with each other which is not supposed to happen.
This is what i have tried.
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.affinity import scale, translate
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def normalize_polygon(polygon_shapefile, output_shapefile):
    """
    Normalizes the coordinates of the polygons in a shapefile to fit within a 0 to 1 range.

    :param polygon_shapefile: Path to the input polygon shapefile.
    :param output_shapefile: Path for the output shapefile with the normalized polygons.
    """
    
    polygon_gdf = gpd.read_file(polygon_shapefile)
    length_polygon = polygon_gdf[polygon_gdf.columns[0]].count()
    normalized_geometries = []
    for i in range(length_polygon):
        geometry = polygon_gdf.loc[i].geometry
        
        # Assume 'geometry' is your initial Polygon object
        bounds = geometry.bounds  # Returns a tuple (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

        # Calculate the range for x and y
        x_range = bounds[2] - bounds[0]  # maxx - minx
        y_range = bounds[3] - bounds[1]  # maxy - miny

        # Normalize coordinates to the range [0, 1]
        normalized_coords = [((x - bounds[0]) / x_range, (y - bounds[1]) / y_range) for x, y in geometry.exterior.coords]

        # Create a new polygon with these normalized coordinates
        normalized_polygon = Polygon(normalized_coords)
        normalized_geometries.append(normalized_polygon)
    
    polygon_gdf.geometry = normalized_geometries
    print(polygon_gdf)
    polygon_gdf.to_file(output_shapefile)
    
input_log = "input.shp"
output_log = "output.shp"

normalize_polygon(input_log, output_log)





"Normalizes the coordinates of the polygons in a shapefile to fit within a 0 to 1 range." - doesn't that mean that the shapes will be fitted to the 0,0 to 1,1 area, which does indeed mean they overlap? What exactly did you expect the outcome to be?

@Grismar I have added an image, which is similar to what i want. I am trying to create training image for yolov5. when i draw manually in roboflow and extract the cordinates and plot it, there is no overlap.

I'm not sure if the answer from user @Timeless is sufficient for you, but the image in their answer does make it very clear what the expected outcome is.

A bit similar to your previous question where you do the transformation relative to the bounds of each single geometry (i.e Polygon) instead of the total_bounds of the entire shapefile. A quick fix would be to remove bounds = geometry.bounds and put bounds = polygon_gdf.total_bounds right before the loop :

